# How to set correct margins

Tags: android, layout, coding-style, custom-titlebar

I have this layout code which I thought was correct:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dip"
    android:background="@drawable/title_background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/title_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_margin="16dip"
        android:src="@drawable/title_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout has a height of 64dip and the first ImageView has a height of 48dip.  From the math I learned a long time ago a margin of 8dip would match perfectly.  But it doesn't as my ImageViews are clipped at the bottom.  This is for a custom titlebar and I have set the android:windowTitleSize to match 64dip in the theme.

Is there some sort of hidden padding on the titlebar?  And if so, what's it size?

Comment: might Hierarchy View be of any help? (and what about image scaling?...)

Comment: I wish. Since the last update none of the tools work properly. Took me some time to barely get Eclipse running. Thanx though. I don't have any problems getting it to look nice, I just wanted the exact measures. I'll do it the hard way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing it the old fashion way I figured out that the "unknown" padding is 8dip all around.  If this is a fixed value I don't know.  It match perfectly to my 48dip ImageView so with a margin of 0dip it is centered.  The second ImageView need a margin of 8dip to be centered top-bottom.

Custom titlebar documentation is very rare so this is as far as I get now.

EDIT:

The background image I created for the titlebar is a 9 patch image with a content area.  This is the "unknown" padding.  So to sum it up - a custom titlebar does not have a hidden padding, but if one uses a 9 patch background image with a content area, the padding would be what's outside that content area.  Basically everything is as it shuld be using a 9 patch image as a background...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/title_icon"
        android:scaleType="center" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

/>

Comment: The problem is not getting it to center. The problem is that I want to know what the padding is for a custom titlebar. The height of the ImageView are 48dip, then with a margin of 2x8dip plus the unknown padding - the sum is more than the 64dip the height of my LinearLayout is. So I just want to know what the unknown padding is so I can set the correct margin without having to guess it.